# Flutter HTTP POST response very slow in Nexus 5X API-24 emulator

Tags: android, flutter, emulation

I am using Nexus 5X API-24 emulator for developing Flutter app. The http post request was in expected speed for last few days but suddenly from today, it is taking more than 10 second for each response. Whereas same response in Postmen is taking just average 47 milliseconds. Also in actual phone devices, responses are very fast like Postman. What could be problem in emulator or Android Studio? I need this emulator working properly as emulator is very handy for rapid development. Help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: open emulator: click three dots at bottom; go to cellular and then make sure:--> network: full;signal:great;voice: home;data:home

Comment: Changed to full, great and home, but still same problem!?

Comment: Maybe the emulator got corrupted somehow.  You could try resetting its state completely, making sure the emulator is powered off and on, or creating a new identical emulator.

Comment: Did reset Emulator to its initial state using Wipe Data and no improvement yet. Created another new emulator as well, but same result as before!

Comment: try:1. same emulator-> different post request 2.different emulator -> same post request. and post the results

Answer (score 1):

of course, there is a problem in your emulator, may these solutions can help you.

1. Reset your emulator from the android studio, cool boot, clear memory
2. make sure you have a good internet connection in your emulator, many times this is the problem
3. re-install the app, after cleaning your emulator

other options: 
 4. update flutter SDK, this may help

Comment: Yes this is fine with real device. Also i have uninstalled Android Studio and Emulator and installed it back but same result

Comment: is your emulator showing good internet connection, also try updating your flutter SDK, if it still doesn't solve the problem then                                                                This issue is not related to Fluter or Http plugin itself. Something in your network is slowing things down or some API setting that has different logic for different clients attaching to it. TRY USING DIFFERENT NETWORK / WIFI